# How to write a go back code so after the user selects a case he/she can go back to the last option?

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

```
package thecashmachin;

import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TheCashMachin {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int pin, proceed2=0, withdraw, dailydraw, Proceed, proceed3 = 0;
    double balance;
    Scanner pinnumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner proc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner withd = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner Next = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner proc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    balance = 9999.99;

    dailydraw = 1000;
     System.out.println(
            "text .");
    System.out.println("1)Proceed");
    System.out.println("2)Return Card");

        Proceed = Next.nextInt();
        switch (Proceed) {

        case 1:// Proceed
            System.out.println("Please enter your 5 digit pin below.");
            Scanner Pin = new Scanner(System.in);
            int Pincode = Pin.nextInt();
            if (Pincode > 9999 && Pincode < 99999) {
                System.out.println("1)Display Balance");
                System.out.println("2)Withdraw Cash");
                System.out.println("3)Other services");
                proceed2 = proc2.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.err.println(
                        "text");
            }

            break;

        case 2:// Return Card
            System.err.println("text");

            break;

        default:
            System.err.println(
                    "text");

            break;}




    switch (proceed2) {

    case 1:
        System.out.println("Your balance today is:  9999.99");
```

/*
* so right here the balance is shown and in real life you would have a go back button to display the other options but on my code after the balance is displayed you cant do anything else have to re run the the script i want a code that if selected goes back to the last option*/

```
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Amount to withdraw");
        withdraw = withd.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please take the cash");
        System.out.println("Current Balance" + " " + (balance - withdraw));
        System.out.println("Daily withdraw left:" + (dailydraw - withdraw));
        if (withdraw > dailydraw) {

            System.err.println("text");
        }
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Would you like to;");
        System.out.println("1)Order a check");
        System.out.println("2)Order a Statement");
        proceed3 = proc3.nextInt();
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("text");

    }


    switch (proceed3) {

    case 1:

        System.out.println("Your check has been orderd");

        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("Your Statement has been orderd");
        break;


    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "How do i input a loop"?

Comment: You dont _input_ a loop. You might want to take input inside a loop

Answer (score 1):

```
DO
    BOOLEAN = TRUE;
    SWITCH() // WITH THE DIFFERENT CASES
    DEFAULT BOOLEAN = FALSE;
WHILE BOOLEAN IS FALSE;
```

This should do. Use a simple do while loop.
Before entering the `switch`, your boolean is set to `TRUE` and if it comes to the `default` it turns it to `FALSE` and you loop until the boolean stays `TRUE`

Comment: When I do this the String set on default keeps looping without stopping

Answer (score 1):

An easy way I know is just making a Boolean before which is kept same as default..

```
boolean test = True;
while (test)
{
    switch(Proceed)
    {

        case 1://Proceed
            System.out.println("Please enter your 5 digit pin below.");
            Scanner Pin=new Scanner(System.in);
            int Pincode=Pin.nextInt();
            test = false;
            break;

        case 2://Return Card
            System.err.println("Your card is being ejected.\n Please Wait..");
            test = false;
            break;

        default:
            System.err.println("Sorry your request could not be processed.\n Please enter the pin again.\n")
            // when neither case is true, keeps loop running.
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this the String set on default keeps looping without stopping

Comment: Would you like me to revise the code you have in your question so it is more easily readable and without error? I have a hard time finding the problem when I'm being distracted by a couple of things :x